XmlParser is vulnerable to XML external entity (XXE) vulnerability GHSA-58qw-p7qm-5rvh - org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml
We recently conducted a scan using AWS Inspector and identified the following vulnerability: GHSA-58qw-p7qm-5rvh affecting org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml.
Here is the description of the vulnerability.[XmlParser is vulnerable to XML external entity (XXE) vulnerability.
XmlParser is being used when parsing Jetty’s xml configuration files. An attacker might exploit
this vulnerability in order to achieve SSRF or cause a denial of service. One possible scenario is importing a (remote) malicious WAR into a Jetty’s server, while the
WAR includes a malicious web.xml.]
We tried to upgrade the org.eclipse.jetty version to V12 as recommended. However, we encountered an error when spinning up the Solr pod.
The error is:
o.e.j.x.XmlParser SAX Parse Issue @null line:198 col:33 : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 198; columnNumber: 33; Attribute value "RewriteHandler" of type ID must be unique within the document.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.

Does any expert know how to resolve this error?

Can you check jetty.xml on the server, the file contains an element with id RewriteHandler as below.

This id should be defined uniquely on the xml file. There might be duplicate id's with name RewriteHandler on the file. Can you remove the duplicate element from the file and restart SOLR again.
Hope this helps!!!
